# Android: how to use dmtracedump

Tags: android

Trying to use dmtracedump tool.

in command line I write: dmtracedump -0 path_to_trace

And I'v got ERROR: unable to read 1333896 bytes from trace file

Is that tool works at all ? Or I do something wrong ?

Comment: You can use that tool directly from Eclipse and it works there (DDMS view, little [Start Method Profiling](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html#how-ddms-works) button).

Comment: Yes, I know about this...I just want to know how to use dmtracedump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: *on Windows, that tool doesn't work at all*. It apparently is no longer maintained since [traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html) became available (both from the command line or from Eclipse DDMS).

Ubuntu, Mac OSX et al should be fine, but that probably doesn't help you much.

As a sidenote, your example command line has a typo: it's -o, not -0.

Comment: I disagree that the tool doesn't work at all - I used it today and it worked fine.  My environment is MacOSX with an up-to-date Eclipse ADT environment, with trace files from a Nexus 5.

Comment: You are right, my answer was based purely on the Windows version. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: As of May 2015, dmtracedump.exe works correctly on Windows for me when generating a text or HTML report from a ddms trace file.

Answer (score 5):

Do you try to use '`dmtracedump`' tool in the windows OS?

I think '`dmtracedump`' tool can't handle big files.. in my case.. Windows 7 32 bit.

> Cmd> dmtracedump -g abc.png Large_Log.trace
>
> ERROR: unable to read 8910087 bytes from trace file
>
> Cannot read trace.

but, I succeeded to generate call graph image file in the ubuntu 64 bit OS.

the size of generated abc.png file is approximately 6 MB.

Comment: dmtracedump works like a champ on Mac (Mavericks). You just need to install Graphviz first! I pulled a TraceView from DDMS tool and then used the command noted above to graph it. Nice!