# error using dmtracedump in windows

Tags: android

Exact duplicate of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565332/android-how-to-use-dmtracedump) ,Im am trying to use dmtracedump in windows with following command

```
dmtracedump.exe -h C:\Users\hemanth.m\Desktop\ddms3079126885013841451.trace
```

and im getting following error

```
ERROR: unable to read 6085766 bytes from trace file
Cannot read trace.
```

I changed the augments of dmtracedump command but error still persists .
I read previous SO questions [dmtracedump doesn't work, HELP!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364833/dmtracedump-doesnt-work-help) and  [Android-Command to run dmtracedump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565332/android-how-to-use-dmtracedump) . All I understood is that the graph cant be generated in windows system and dmtracedump no more supports -g -h augments  except -o .

I desperately wanted to use the graphical representation of call stack in the form of the graph using(graphviz) in windows .

My question is , Is there anything that can be done to dmtracedump to accept -h,-g aurguments ,i mean a patch to this existing tool something like .bat files which links both dmtracedump tool and graphviz . 
  Or tell me the flow diagram to create a patch .

Or how can i use ddms****.trace file to generate a graph of call stack using any other tool directly with or without dmtracedump and graphviz .

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm also getting the same error..

Comment: @vidyasagar :no in windows .But i heard it works in linux.. try  your luck

Comment: To generate a call stack image I ran `dmtracedebug -o outfile.png ddms_input.trace` but this was on OSX.  Make sure you have graphviz installed and added to your PATH.